# SOAP stub not serializing

Tags: .net, soap, cisco

I am attempting to serialize a property named numOfResults to `SOAP` message attribute, however the property does not serialize into the post when I view it in `Wireshark`.  I have changed the name and it does it fine and I have even recreated it from fresh calling it other names and it serializes, but as soon as I call it "numOfResults" it does not. Note, this is within a generated stub, which was generated from the WSDL sometime ago (in .NET 2) and I cannot get access to the schema or .wsdl to generate a new stub.

Unfortunately the service is communicating with a closed box, so I cannot change the attribute name at the other end.  I have rebuilt the project in `.NET 2.0` and `.NET 4.5` with same result.  The program has also been run on `Windows 8` and `Winserver 2008`, also with the same result.

I wonder if "numOfResults" is reserved word somewhere in the bowels of the framework.

Otherwise any ideas of what I should try next or what the problem could be?

Regards

Mark

Comment: `numOfResults` should not affect your serialization as it is not a keyword. Make sure you have both getter\setter to serialize a property. Please paste your code.

Comment: [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public int numOfResults
        {
            get
            {
                return this.numOfResultsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.numOfResultsField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("numOfResults");
            }
        }

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is standard construction auto-generated by wsdl, Version=2.0.50727.42

Comment: Instead of viewing in Wireshark, write the ouput of serialization to a `FileStream` and see if the property is serialized.

Comment: Resolved the issue by adding the attribute name to the constructor of the attribute and changing name of the property as follows...Bit of hack but didn't have any other option [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("numOfResults")]
        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute(0)]
        public int nOfResults
        {
            get
            {
                return this.numOfResultsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.numOfResultsField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("numOfResults");
            }
        }

Comment: Hope you find a better answer another day :)